# How to make "Exercise" section

Tags: environments

How can I make an environment like this?

```
1-15. (Section 1 exercise 15): lorem ipsum
      | <- start here
      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out, all you need to do is customize the enumerate environment after the `label` option for the required margins and indentations by using the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercise 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection-\arabic*.,leftmargin=0.5in,labelsep=0.25in]
\item \lipsum[1-2]
\item \lipsum[3-4]
\end{enumerate}
\section{Exercise 2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection-\arabic*.,leftmargin=0.5in,labelsep=0.25in]
\item \lipsum[5-6]
\item \lipsum[7-8]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```